# How to make sure no execution path reaches a certain line at compile time

Tags: c++

Say I have a line of code in a function and I don't want there to be any execution path that could reach it. 
I could place an assert(false), but I'd rather have the compiler check that for me. 
Any ideas?

Example:

Consider the following code (please do not comment on the use of goto, it isn't the point here).

```
    // Code block starts withsome branching code.
    // By the end of this branching code, we MUST goto one of the labels below.
    // Not jumping to one of the labels is invalid, and I want to prevent 
    // that from happenning (this can be checked at compile time).

    if (...) {
        if (...) {
            goto labelA;
        }
        // The lack of a goto here is a fallthrough bug case which should not happen.
    } else if (...) {
        goto labelB;
    } else {
        goto labelC;
    }

    // -------------------- this point should not be reached. -----------------------------

labelA:
    ...
    goto final;
labelB:
    ...
    goto final;
labelC:
    ...
    goto final;
labelD:
    ...
    goto final;
final:
    return status;
```

Comment: So if you don't want any execution path to reach you never want it to be executed?  If you have a line of code that you never want to run but want to keep the line just comment it out.

Comment: You could try to enable as many warnings as possible. Some compilers warn when code could not be reached. But this will not catch all cases.

Comment: I could place a goto at that line which jumps to a line past the return statement, then if the compiler detected it could be reached, I'd have a "not all code paths return a value". The problem with this approach is that it won't work on void functions...

Comment: @Werner, but that is exactly the opposite. I want an error to pop if it CAN be reached, not if it can't.

Comment: Can you explain a real use case for this? What about situations where this is true but compiler does not hane enough information?

Comment: @saarraz1 Yep, my idea was not the best. Yet if the compiler warns you that there is some code like an assert that can't be reached you can be sure that this code will not be reached. You will not catch all cases, but might get some of them. But: YOU should know if code can be reached or not. If it can't you should delete it. It you don't know then add asserts.

Comment: You may still create rule with libclang to check that... Not trivial...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Restructure your code to use modern flow control structures and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @saarraz1, you may abuse of `goto` for function not returning `void`:

```
int foo(int i)
{
    int res = 0;
    if (i % 2) {
        if (i % 3) {
            goto labelA;
        }
        // The lack of a goto here is a fallthrough bug case which should not happen.
    } else if (i % 3) {
        goto labelB;
    } else {
        goto labelC;
    }

    goto labelNoReturn; // -- this point should not be reached. --

labelA:
    res = 1;
    goto final;
labelB:
    res = 2;
    goto final;
labelC:
    res = 3;
    goto final;
final:
    return res;
labelNoReturn:
    {} 
}
```

to have warning similar to

```
main.cpp:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76433f822832ab2c)

Comment: Except surely you _don't_ want the warning in this case? Because every execution path results in a `return`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we do have an execution path that results in a no-return (every i not divisible by 2 nor by 3 will cause it).

Comment: correction - every i not divisible by 2 but divisible by 3 will cause it.

Comment: @saarraz1: Ah yes okay. Wow that's easy to miss. You really should refactor this. At least now I see why you asked this question.